# All Matplotlib points appearing at bottom of graph, regardless of y-value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, linear-regression

I'm following [this linear regression tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOppzHpvTiQ&list=PL2-dafEMk2A7YdKv4XfKpfbTH5z6rEEj3). Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

dataframe = pd.read_fwf('brain_body.txt')
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)

plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
plt.plot(x_values, body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

When I run the script, I get no errors, but the graph doesn't seem to account for the y-values. I reduced the data points to three so it's easier to see:

[image]

I tried to manually change the y-axis with `plt.ylim([-1000,7000])` but no luck.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You have one value that is exceeding all others by several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code, it's just that you have a few very extreme values in relation to the rest of your data.  Matplotlib expands the graph to show the extreme values, but that ends up in bunching all the others.  Broadening your `ylim` will only increase the effect - try a much smaller `ylim` and `xlim` instead:

```
plt.ylim([0, 20])
plt.xlim([0, 2])
```

[image: plot]